# Json not saving locally in flutter

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I'm having a problem with my flutter project, I would like to save json code locally on the device, but it's not saving. I wrote a piece of code that should save locally, however it didn't do what I was expecting:

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Add Items',
      home: AddItemScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class AddItemScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AddItemScreenState createState() => _AddItemScreenState();
}

class _AddItemScreenState extends State<AddItemScreen> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final _nameController = TextEditingController();
  final _quantityController = TextEditingController();

  List<Habit> _itemList = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    readItemsFromJson().then((items) {
      setState(() {
        _itemList = items;
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _nameController.dispose();
    _quantityController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Add Item'),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        child: Form(
          key: _formKey,
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16.0),
                child: ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () async {
                    final newItem = Habit(
                      name: 'habit ${_itemList.length.toString()}',
                      daysOfWeek: [true, true, true, true, true, true, true],
                      icon: Icons.check_box,
                      startTime: DateTime.now(),
                      endTime: DateTime.now(),
                      goals: List.empty(),
                    );
                    await addItemToJson(newItem);
                    setState(() {
                      _itemList.add(newItem);
                    });
                  },
                  child: Text('Add'),
                ),
              ),
              Text(
                'JSON:',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: _itemList.length,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    return ListTile(
                      title: Text(_itemList[index].name),
                      leading: Icon(_itemList[index].icon),
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

// The model class for an item
class Habit {
  String name;
  List<bool> daysOfWeek;
  IconData icon;
  DateTime startTime;
  DateTime endTime;
  List<dynamic> goals;

  Habit({
    required this.name,
    required this.daysOfWeek,
    required this.icon,
    required this.startTime,
    required this.endTime,
    required this.goals,
  });

  factory Habit.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Habit(
      name: json['name'] as String,
      daysOfWeek: json['daysOfWeek'] as List<bool>,
      icon: IconData(json['icon'] as int, fontFamily: 'MaterialIcons'),
      startTime: DateTime.parse(json['startTime'] as String),
      endTime: DateTime.parse(json['endTime'] as String),
      goals: json['goals'] as List<dynamic>,
    );
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        'name': name,
        'daysOfWeek': daysOfWeek,
        'icon': icon.codePoint,
        'startTime': startTime.toIso8601String(),
        'endTime': endTime.toIso8601String(),
        'goals': goals,
      };
}

// Returns the path to the app's local file
Future<File> get _localFile async {
  final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
  return File('${directory.path}/items.json');
}

// Reads the items from the local JSON
Future<List<Habit>> readItemsFromJson() async {
  try {
    final file = await _localFile;
    if (!file.existsSync()) {
      return [];
    }
    final jsonString = await file.readAsString();
    final jsonList = jsonDecode(jsonString) as List<dynamic>;
    final items = jsonList.map((json) => Habit.fromJson(json)).toList();
    return items;
  } catch (e) {
    print('Error reading items from JSON file: $e');
    return [];
  }
}

// Adds an item to the local JSON
Future<void> addItemToJson(Habit item) async {
  try {
    final file = await _localFile;
    List<dynamic> jsonList = [];
    if (file.existsSync()) {
      final jsonString = await file.readAsString();
      jsonList = jsonDecode(jsonString) as List<dynamic>;
    }
    jsonList.add(item.toJson());
    await file.writeAsString(jsonEncode(jsonList));
  } catch (e) {
    print('Error adding item to JSON file: $e');
  }
}
```

I've tried it both on web and iOS, but when I reloaded the runner, the items in the list dissapeared. Seems like the json is not saving locally.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: I would suggest looking in the directory whether the file was actually created and if it has the correct content